# What is web.session.Session in the python web.py module

Tags: python, web.py

I'm currently learning Python and can't work out what the `web.session.Session` is in the follow game program:

```
app = web.application(urls, globals())
session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), initializer={'room': None})
```

What are `app`, `Diskstore`, and `initializer`?

Comment: app and initializer are defined right there in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

This `web.session` module gives you the session support,

- `initializer` - You can set the initial session which is not mandatory.

  eg: `initializer={'room': None}` sets the initial session of room to None.
- `DiskStore` makes the session to save in disk whereas `DBStore` stores session in databases.
- `app` gives the application instance created as
  `web.application(urls, globals())` with URLs which mapped to the relevant classes.

Refer [this](http://webpy.org/cookbook/sessions).